# Cannot connect to cloudant database using ipython at bluemix

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am following the tutorial of IBM bluemix and try to extract data from the crimes db just created at cloudant db. I am using ipython notebook.

I have got error when trying to connect to the database

The tutorial is as follows:
https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/spark/get-started/use-python-notebook-to-load-cloudant-data-into-spark/

I have created the db at cloudant accordingly but got the error when trying to connnect to the db

---

```
<pre>
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _rev: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geometry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- compnos: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- domestic: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fromdate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- main_crimecode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- naturecode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- reptdistrict: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- shooting: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7370c766a2d0> in <module>()
      9 
     10 
---> 11 cloudantdata.select("properties.naturecode").show()
     12 
     13 

/usr/local/src/bluemix_ipythonspark_141/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n)
    256         +---+-----+
    257         """
--> 258         print(self._jdf.showString(n))
    259 
    260     def __repr__(self):

/usr/local/src/bluemix_ipythonspark_141/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/src/bluemix_ipythonspark_141/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.9 in stage 7.0 (TID 29, yp-spark-dal09-env5-0046): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 8
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$.convertRowWithConverters(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$4.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RDDConversions$$anonfun$rowToRowRdd$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExistingRDD.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1775)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1775)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:801)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
</pre>
```

---

"Procedure 2: Create a Python notebook to analyze the Cloudant data"

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

cloudantdata = sqlContext.read.format("com.cloudant.spark").\
option("cloudant.host","borischow.cloudant.com").\
option("cloudant.username", "borischow").\
option("cloudant.password","xxxxxx").\
load("crimes")


cloudantdata.printSchema()
cloudantdata.count()


cloudantdata.select("properties.naturecode").show()


disturbDF = cloudantdata.filter("properties.naturecode = 'DISTRB'")
disturbDF.show()


disturbDF.select("properties").write.format("com.cloudant.spark").\
option("cloudant.host","borischow.cloudant.com").\
option("cloudant.username", "borischow").\
option("cloudant.password","xxxxxx").\
save("crimes_filtered")
```

Comment: I just hit the same problem.  I'll do some investigating and let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have encountered a known issue that is reported in this ticket: https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/issues/24.